# Taking care about many "Tor doesn't connect" question

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answers, unanswered-questions, reviewing

When you browse Tor.SE you'll find lots of questions were Tor doesn't connect. Some people use plain Tor, other use bridges and some other people try to access onion services. I started to collect some sites today. You'll find the list in a [pad](https://pad.systemli.org/p/TorSE-connect).

Depending on the question I want either to have some kind of "super question" plus answer which discusses several connection problems and their solutions or to have a main answer and other questions are closed as dupes.

First I'd ask you to add sites to the [document](https://pad.systemli.org/p/TorSE-connect), so that we get an overview. Second I'd like to know what your favorite solution would be.